# jdbc sqlite returns no rows

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

```
public ArrayList<Booking> getAllBookings(){
    ArrayList<Booking> list = new ArrayList<Booking>();
    int rowCount = 0;
    try {           
        stmt = connection.createStatement();     
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Bookings";          
        ResultSet rows = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 
        rows.last();
        System.out.println("Row Count "+rows.getRow());
        rows.beforeFirst();
        connection.commit();           

        while (rows.next()){
            Booking b = new Booking();
            otherStuff();
            list.add(b);
            rowCount++;
        }
        stmt.close();
        rows.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }     

    System.out.println("There were " +rowCount + " records.");
    return list;
}
```

Why do I not get any rows returned? I am connecting using this:

```
public static Connection dbConnect(){
 try {     
     Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
     Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:/test/test_db.sqlite3");
     System.out.println("Connection Succesful");
     return connection;
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e);
     return null;
 } }
```

When running SQLite Studio my query returns the correct results, but here my output on console is:

```
Connection Succesful
(Row Count + rows.getRow() is not printing here for some reason)
There were 0 records.
```

Comment: Do you have records in Bookings table and are you connecting to proper database?

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace()` inside your empty catch block.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned I am using SQLite Studio to view my database and test my queries. I can see my returned rows on there.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: database in auto-commit mode
 at org.sqlite.Conn.commit(Conn.java:342)

This is from the stacktrace

Comment: So, in auto-commit mode, you cannot use `commit`. And never leave a `catch` block empty unless you know with absolute certainty no exception will ever be thrown.

Comment: Ok setting Auto Commit to false has solved my problem, I am now getting the rows as I should.

Comment: Thanks, yeah you are right it was stupid of me to leave the catch block empty